# Saving multiple constant values used in multiple files

Tags: c, variables, constants

I am creating a large application with a large amount of constant values that are used during the entire run of the application but that sometimes changed in between uses, sensor parameters and so on. In Python which I am quite comfortable with I simply use a separate file where I store all the variables, using all caps to indicate a constant value as follows (just and example):

```
IP = "169.254.98.220"      # The ip used to connect to the LiDAR via Ethernet
SAMPLES_PER_SCAN = 2400    # number of scans collected in one revolution
SCAN_FREQUENCY = 35        # Hz, note that a high samples_per_scan can require a low scan_frequency
USE_FILTER = False         # Uses a filter to average 5 incoming scans into one
```

However I want to know what the recommended way to store the same type of values in C. I could not find the answer, I'm sure the answer can be found somewhere but I can not find it, maybe I'm using the wrong search keywords.

Is the best way to do "the same" as I do in python by using a single file for all variables and then use a header file to share them between files?

Comment: If that works for you in Python, then do something similar in C.  Constant values can be created in a header file (or multiple header files.) and `#included` when necessary.

Comment: If it are configuration values, read them from a text file. If it are compilation constants put them in an include file.

Comment: @ryyker is it "okey" to declare values in a header file? I've come to understand that header files are not supposed to contain any "data" but only to share functions etc.

Comment: Possibly you could write a simple configuration file which is read by your program and startup, and saved on program exit. It's not trivial to implement this, but there are plenty of libraries which could help with this.

Comment: its ok to define macros in header files `#define` . All the constants in you example can be set as macros.

Comment: _is it "okey" to declare values in a header file?_.   Header files can be used this way, and it is not uncommon to use thiem in this way, but I only made that recommendation because you stated that you commonly use it in Python.  However I am much more in favor of using @wildplasser's suggestion.  Reading in  text, or `csv` file specific to the needs of the program are a better approach.  I have used both methods, and both are acceptable.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, I will try that out

Comment: BTW: often the *factory defaults* come from #define constants, The runtime configuration just fixes them up. This could come from a command (language) or an init configuration, or both.

Comment: You could also declare constants in a header file (`extern const int X;`) and define them in an implementation file (`const int X = 23;`). Some coding styleguides turn down the usage of `#define` because of its countless possibilities for errors. This is also the way to go for non-trivial values like structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"recommended way to store the same type of values in C. I could not find the answer,..."*

Without knowing more about your immediate *purpose/plans*, the question does not have a *right* answer,  only guesses. Following are some guiding suggestions based on *scope of project* assumptions.

*Header file defined constants*:
If this is a quick prototype or proof of concept, then using the header file approach is likely to be completely adequate.  This *probably* depends on how *large*  the *“…large amount of constant values…”* actually is.   It’s all really up to you.  Depending on how patient you are about editing all those values, and how meticulous you are when accuracy of value is important. If just 10-20 items, then okay,  If much larger than that, I would choose to nix the header file idea and use either a configuration file, or database entry.
*Disadvantage* - This is not run-time adjustable.  What is defined at compile time is the behavior you will get at run-time.
*Advantage* – simple to implement. (Using `#defines`, `extern` scoped variables, and `macro` definitions is easy and well documented)

*External initialization file/database*:
If project is well defined, and fairly well along in development, and uses a large number of configuration values, then reading from external storage (whether it be file or database.) is probably best.  Once implemented this will supports maximum run-time flexibility with minimal effort.
Disadvantage – This requires more time and rigor during implementation.  The code to read in a file does not have to be complicated as long as the file is syntactically strict, and does not require frequent changes to field definitions, or count of fields.
Advantage – Maximum run-time flexibility.  Can use run-time prompting of user to input which file/database table to use during run-time session, etc.

Below is a very simple concept for reading a simple file (such as the one your post describes)  Even though this will compile and build, treat it as pseudo code and modify/expand  as needs dictate.

```
enum {//enum values useful to use as indexes to struct values during initialization
    IP,
    SAMPS_PER_SCAN,
    SCAN_FREQUENCY,
    USE_FILTER,
    MEMBERS_MAX
};
//Useful during file read to test record field name 
//against coded field strings prior to parsing field 
//data value into struct
const char members[][20] = {"IP","SCAN_FREQUENCY","SCAN_FREQUENCY","USE_FILTER"};

int get_member_index(const char *mem);//prototype helper function

typedef struct {//struct designed to match configuration dataset
    char ipAddr[20];
    int sPerScan;
    double sfreq;
    bool filter;
}params_s;

params_s params;//create instance of struct parameters

int main(void)
{
    int index = 0;
    char line[80] = {0}; //change size bases on known actual file contents
    char *tok = NULL;
    
    FILE *fp = fopen(".\\data.txt", "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
        {
          //This is where file is parse
            index = get_member_index(line);
            if(index < 0)
            {
                //error message to user that file is corrupt or incorrect
                //exit program, or provide try again loop to enter another file name
            }
            else
            {
                switch(index)  {//parse data according to type of each parameter
                    case IP:
                        //use strtok or scanf strchr combination to extract value from string
                        tok = strtok(line, "=\" ");//consume first part of line
                        tok = strtok(NULL, "=\" ");  
                        strcpy(params.ipAddr, tok);
                        break;
                    case SAMPS_PER_SCAN:
                       tok = strtok(line, "= ");//consume first part of line
                       tok = strtok(NULL, "= ");//get value
                       params.sPerScan = atoi(tok);
                        break;
                    case SCAN_FREQUENCY:
                        //construt parse for double
                        break;
                    case USE_FILTER:
                        //construct parse for bool
                        break;
                };
                    
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);//file no longer needed, close it
        
        //use captured struct parameter data throughout code
        //via passing as function argument.
    }
    return 0;
}
//helper function to get index of parameter in data line
int get_member_index(const char *mem)
{
    for(int i=0;i<MEMBERS_MAX; i++)
    {
        if(strstr(mem, members[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The testing and proof of concept has already been developed and tested using Python. This is more of a translation to C so that the performance is increased (I have already used some Cython but not alot) and mainly since the company wants the final application to be in C. The current implementation has around 40 parameters/constants.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `.h` file containing defines that you would include where you want to use those constants.

For example, your **constants.h** would be:

```
#define IP "169.254.98.220"      // The ip used to connect to the LiDAR via Ethernet
#define SAMPLES_PER_SCAN 2400    // number of scans collected in one revolution
#define SCAN_FREQUENCY 35        // Hz, note that a high samples_per_scan can require a low scan_frequency
#define USE_FILTER false         // Uses a filter to average 5 incoming scans into one
```

And you would just add this line to your `.c` file where you want to use them, assuming the files are located in the same folder:

```
#include "constants.h"
```

Defines are macros that are treated by the pre-compiler so it's basically the same as writing the values everywhere your are using the macro. More info [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC11). And if you want to insert expression like:

```
#define A_NUMBER_PLUS_ANOTHER (42 + 66)
// Don't forget those :       ^       ^
```

Don't forget to add parenthesis without which your operations with macros could lead to  unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a very similar way to what I am used to.